# Alberi Puzzle, no idea where to go

Tags: visual, solvability

The following image is a puzzle I've been stuck in for about a week now, I was wondering how to go about solving it:
[image: very hard puzzle]

The way it works is that any given row, any given column and any given area has two trees in it. Trees may not be adjacent to other trees (vertically, horizontally or diagonally).

As a better example here's one that I've solved (I'm placing a blank version here for those that wish to solve it themselves):
[image: easier puzzle]

> [image: easier puzzle solved]

Also to reiterate, I don't know the solution this. It will be self evident once found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>        -----------------------------------
>       |           |         O |     O |   |
>       |           |           |       |   |
>       |     O     | O         |       |   |
>       |           |    -------     ---    |
>       |           |   |     O     | O     |
>       |        ---|   |           |    ---|
>       | O     | O |   |           |   |   |
>       |-------    |   |-----------    |   |
>       |           |   | O |     O     |   |
>       |           |   |   |-----------    |
>       |     O     |   |   |             O |
>       |    -----------|   |               |
>       |   |         O |   |     O         |
>       |---     -------    |            ---|
>       | O     |           |           | O |
>       |       |        ---------------    |
>       |       | O     | O                 |
>        -----------------------------------
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, elias. I didn't know html tags worked for this.

Comment: How did you solve it?  Trial and error, brute force, or something else?

Comment: I needed some trial and error. When I get stuck I put a tree in a spot that looks like it will lead to lots of forced moves, and so get to a contradiction quickly, or to a solution quickly. The three areas on the left mostly take up 3 columns except for that one cell in the fourth column. My first lucky trial guess was to put a tree there, and hence also at the bottom of the third column, and second from bottom of the last column.

Comment: Cool, Thanks, I've stuck on that for a while.